# SQL join returns fewer rows than non-join

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm using SQL to work with two tables in a database. The tables contain data from a marketing platform. I have checked within the platform and the data matches up when I use the below query.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*),
SUM(a.impressions),
SUM(a.clicks),
SUM(a.spend)
FROM table_1
```

When I use the below query, to access the `name` value from table_2 and apply this to matching entries from table_1, the query returns fewer rows - so the values for `impressions`, `spend` and `clicks` are underreporting. I've tried switching the tables round but this hasn't worked and I'm confused as to why I'm consistently getting an incorrect result.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUBQUERY.name, SUM(SUBQUERY.imp) as imp, SUM(SUBQUERY.clicks) as clicks, SUM(SUBQUERY.spend) as spend from
(
SELECT 
a.impressions as imp,
a.clicks as clicks,
a.spend as spend,
b.name as name
FROM table_1 as a
LEFT JOIN table_2 b
ON a.account_id = b.id  
GROUP BY 
imp,
clicks,
spend, 
name 
) AS SUBQUERY
GROUP BY SUBQUERY.name
```

Example data:

table_1

```
|customer_id | source | campaign_name| campaign_id |  date      |currency | clicks | impressions | spend |
|----------- |--------| ------------ | ----------- | ---------- | ------- | ------ | ----------- | ----- |
| 1234       | google | campaign_1   | 1090        | 2022-01-01 | GBP     | 10     | 23          | 3     |
| 1642       | google | campaign_3   | 1092        | 2022-12-12 | GBP     | 101    | 222         | 36    |

table_2
|customer_id | customer_name |
|----------- | ------------- |
| 1234       | client_1      |
| 1642       | client_2      |
```

Edit: have tested the answers, both actually end up creating a large number of duplicates. I can see these in the count, impression, clicks and spend values. I've removed date from the query to simplify things

Comment: Any chance you could give us sample data (preferrably in an easy to import form) for tables `table_1` and `table_2` and some table definition information like what fields are nullable and any constraints (especially what's got UNIQUE constraints)? That may be obvious to a redshift developer but with a SQL tag you're also getting views outside the redshift developer community.

Comment: There's no reason to have a group by inside the subquery; you're not counting. so if you have multiple record occurring on the same day for impressions, clicks, spend and name, then you're eliminating counts.

Comment: Also; why group by a.date if you're not displaying  it

Comment: Apologies, date should have been removed - I was grouping by date but I was seeing the same issue without

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the simplest

```
SELECT COUNT(*), name, SUM(imppressions) as imp, SUM(clicks) as clicks, SUM(spend) as spend
FROM table_1 a
LEFT JOIN table_2 b
  ON a.account_id = b.id  
GROUP BY a.name
```

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be a misunderstanding on my part with how the data looks in table_2. It's actually as below, so there were already multiple rows for my join condition:

table_2

```
|customer_id | customer_name |
|----------- | ------------- |
| 1234       | client_1      |
| 1642       | client_2      |
| 1642       | client_2      |
| 1234       | client_1      |
| 1234       | client_1      |
```

I was able to resolve the issue by using DISTINCT within my query as below.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*), 
SUM(impressions) as imp, 
SUM(clicks) as clicks, 
SUM(spend) as spend
FROM table_1 as a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(id), name FROM table_2) as b
    ON a.account_id = b.id
GROUP BY b.name
```

If you're having the same issue - check your data!

Comment: What's the key for table 2?  if (ID) isn't a key you're allowing duplicates which will lead to headache down the road.

Comment: There is more data in table_2, it's essentially a record of changes within the account. I didn't fully understand this at the time but this is why the same id can appear multiple times

Answer (score 1):

Your first `GROUP BY imp,clicks,spend, name, date` may be "grouping" rows. Your second `GROUP BY SUBQUERY.name` will only count what is left as different groups

Hard to tell what you are trying to do, but try removing the inner `GROUP BY` and see if this is closer to what you expect?

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUBQUERY.name, SUM(SUBQUERY.imp) as imp, SUM(SUBQUERY.clicks) as clicks, SUM(SUBQUERY.spend) as spend from
(
SELECT 
a.impressions as imp,
a.clicks as clicks,
a.spend as spend,
b.name as name,
a.date as date
FROM table_1 as a
LEFT JOIN table_2 b
ON a.account_id = b.id  
) AS SUBQUERY
GROUP BY SUBQUERY.name
```

Comment: close I think; not sure how date gets handled

Comment: This ends up creating duplicates in the results

Comment: by duplicates do you mean one row per "name" ? do the count(*) s by name add up to the single line count before the join?

Comment: The count(*)s exceed the single line count before the join. The number of impressions, clicks and spend is higher than before the join

Comment: @tommo , I noticed your other answer about duplicates in table_2. this makes sense. My next suggestion was to try a count(id) as well as a count(distinct id) in the same query of table_2 only, and see if it was equal. Last thought, is perhaps there is a table_3 somewhere with distinct rows that you can join to instead of table_2? Or there is room for one to be created...

Comment: There's not one existing, but I will look into creating one